# Pass the full path to the powershell script where it was called from the right-click context menu.

Tags: windows, powershell, arguments, registry, contextmenu

The Powershell script that performs certain activity is placed in the right-click context menu, and can be called from any placed on the file system.

**Q: How to pass argument that contains a full path of place where user clicked on the context menu that has launched the script?**

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" 
-File "D:\Run-CoolScript.ps1" .......
```

Above is stated command in the registry to specify context menu action. Instead of the dots, what should I put so that script know from where it has been launched?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Variable that contains current place from where the context menu has been called by clicking right-click on empty space i `%V`.

So registry Command entry became:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" 
-File "D:\Run-CoolScript.ps1" "%V"
```

N.B. Of course `D:\Run-CoolScript.ps1` has "to know" how to handle the input parameters!

Answer (score 2):

I've used something like this in the past:

```
... -Command `"& {[Environment]::CurrentDirectory=(Set-Location -LiteralPath:'%L' -PassThru).ProviderPath; D:\Run-CoolScript.ps1}`"
```

Or if you aren't making any calls into .NET that relies on the current dir being set correctly you can simplify to this:

```
... -Command `"& {Set-Location -LiteralPath:'%L'; D:\Run-CoolScript.ps1}`"
```

Comment: have you tested this while running from inside the registry, wondering if the %L variable report the current directory that was right clicked on, or that of the Powershell.exe, i.e. `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\`

Comment: It will report the full path IIRC.  If the item is a file then it's the file's fullpath.  So you need to do split-path first e.g. `Set-Location -LiteralPath (Split-Path '%L' -Parent);...`.  BTW the first example comes from PSCX's Enable-PowerShellPromptHere command which adds an "Open Powershell" context menu entry for folders.